# Building a Uniswap Multicall V3 Method with Ethers

Tags: javascript, blockchain, cryptojs, ethers.js, uniswap

I'm trying to build a multicall method (standard swap) with ethers library and JS but running into this error:

```
(0, properties_1.defineReadOnly)(this, "fragments", abi.map(function (fragment) {
                                                                ^

TypeError: abi.map is not a function
```

This is my code and I'm totally sure I'm doing something wrong as this whole multicall is new to me.

Also, how do I add another method into the same multicall? Like an approve of a token. Has someone a working example?

p.s.: I dont want to use web3, rather stick to ethers lib.

```
const params = {
      amountIn: purchaseAmount,
      amountOutMin: 0,
      path: tokenspair,
      to: publicKey
    }

    const data = await ethers.utils.Interface(abi).encodeFunctionData("swapExactTokensForTokens", params)
    
    let unsignedTx = await _router.populateTransaction.multicall(
      data,
      {
        type: 2,
        maxFeePerGas: maxFeePerGas,
        maxPriorityFeePerGas: maxPriorityFeePerGas,
        gasLimit: gasLimit,
        nonce: currentNonce,
        deadline: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 5
      }
    )

    unsignedTx.chainId = chainID
    signedTx = await _wallet.signTransaction(unsignedTx)
```

I checked the ABI and I have the method "swapExactTokensForTokens" in there correctly.

Thanks a ton for helping!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I will share with you some of my experience with this. First at all, multicall is not supported by UniswapV2 Router, you need to use a multicall proxy like de MakerDao multicall contract or use UniswapV3 Router that inherits from its own multicall contract.

I am spotting that you are using UniswapV2 Router because `swapExactTokensForTokens` is a method for that version.

Here is a video that shows how to make a multicall write transaction with Ethers and uniswapV3:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKiLdpshg6w

To understand the video please read first this Uniswap V3 doc:
https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/guides/swaps/single-swaps

Take into account that the dev of the video is using uniswapV3 SDK in order to use their ABI interfaces, but you do not need it. The library artifacts comes with the ABI inherited contracts separately, but you can download the full ABI from etherscan.io and use it as the router v3 contract ABI.